# Draw Chemical reactors

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I was wondering if there is a package or some way of drawing chemical reactors as in the following image

[image: Chemical reactor with inputs and outputs]

I was looking in the documentation of [chemfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig), [streetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/streetex) and [xymtex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymtex) but the closest one was to draw a polygon as suggested in streetex

[image]

But I'm not sure if it's the best way and then how to manage to add the input and outputs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, I just find the [chemplants](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/chemplants/chemplants-doc.pdf) package, If I can, in a while I willl publish an answer to my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [chemistry tag](https://ctan.org/topic/chemistry) in CTAN I found the [chemplants package](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/chemplants/chemplants-doc.pdf), which uses [PGF (TkiZ)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

It has a lot of figures you can use. In the example below I used and `stirred reactor` and for labeling. I used `nodes`, inside them you can't put many things so I used the `parbox` to group the text and components I needed.

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Math   %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\%}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Chemistry   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemplants}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    \adjustbox{center=\textwidth}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %%%% Arrows left %%%%

            \draw[main stream] (1 ,3) -- (3 ,3);
            \node[above] at (1 ,3) {
                \parbox{3cm}{
                    \scriptsize
                    \textbf{$\dot{M}_1$}
                    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, nolistsep]
                            \item \SI{20}{\percent} $H_2S$ \newline
                            \item \SI{80}{\percent} $CH_4$
                        \end{itemize}
                }
            };

            \draw[main stream] (1 ,2) -- (3 ,2);
            \node[below] at (1 ,2) {
                \parbox{3cm}{
                    \scriptsize
                    \textbf{$\dot{M}_2$}
                    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, nolistsep]
                        \item $SO_2$
                    \end{itemize}
                }
            };

            %%%% Reactor %%%%

            \pic (Reactor) at (4,2.5) {stirred reactor};

            %%%% Arrows below %%%%

            \draw[main stream] (4 , 1.25) -- (4 , 0);
            \node[below] at (4,0) {
                \parbox{2cm}{
                    \begin{center}
                        {\bf S} \\
                        \SI{5000}{lb}
                    \end{center}
                }
            };

            %%%% Arrows right %%%%

            \draw[main stream] (5 , 2.5) -- (7 , 2.5);
            \node[right] at (7,2.5) {
                \parbox{3cm}{
                    \scriptsize
                    \textbf{$\dot{M}_3$}
                    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, nolistsep]
                        \item $k_1\space SO_2$
                        \item $k_2\space H_2S$
                        \item $k_3\space H_2O$
                        \item $k_4\space CH_4$
                    \end{itemize}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

The output it's beautiful

[image]

Comment: Instead of math mode you may want to use a package dedicated to chemical formulae such as chemformula or mhchem.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Be aware that English people talk about "native language". ;-)